# Windows Phone 8: Open jpeg in C++ code

Tags: c++, image-processing, file-io, windows-phone-8, jpeg

I want to load jpeg images located in the isolated storage of a Windows Phone 8 app from C++ code. One solution is to use libjpeg or any other 3rd party library. But is it also possible to load a jpeg directly with a built-in function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows native image api (WIC) is not supported on native windows phone 8 api:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662930(v=vs.105).aspx

I guess in .net there is something which can load jpeg (would be surprising if it didn't) but you should write some wrapper to call managed code from native c++. I don't know the detail for that (usually people want to do the opposite).

Comment: Loading jpegs from managed C# code is no problem but I prefer a solution where I don't have to "mess" around with C# or libjpeg.

Comment: the windows phone 8 native api set is very limited, and it's explicitly said that you can't use the image loading apis, so i guess you can only choose whether you prefer to mess around with .net or libjpeg. If you're only targeting windows phone i think .net is your best choice.

Comment: also, the link I posted is dated 15/3/2013, so it is very likely not to be outdated